# ¿Por qué no reconoce los paquetes previamente instalados un ambiente virtual de python?

Tags: python, pip

Buen día a todos. Me surgió un inconveniente al trabajar con un ambiente virtual de Python. Espero me puedan apoyar.

Todo es correcto al activar el ambiente virtual  con el comando en terminal "`venv\Scripts\activate.bat`" .

A la extrema izquierda se confirma que esta activado el ambiente virtual con "`(venv)`". A la hora de explorar los paquetes instalados con el comando "pip list" o "pip freeze" me lanza que solo hay dos paquetes, que son pip y setuptools.

Pero al explorar la carpeta `venv/Lib/site-packages` me aparecen todos los paquetes que había instalado con anterioridad.

Hice la prueba de instalar un paquete cualquiera de nuevo en el ambiente y me lo instala globalmente en python.

Alguien sabe por que esta sucediendo esto? He intentado acceder a otros ambientes virtuales de otros proyectos en donde si funciona correctamente todo.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Parece que estás trabajando en windows. Prueba a poner el comendo `where python` y `where pip` una vez activado el ambiente. Esos comandos te reportan la ruta hacia los ejecutables python y pip que se estarán considerando. Debería salirte una ruta que apunta a la carpeta /bin de tu ambiente, pero con el comportamiento que describes apuesto a que al menos en el caso de pip te está usando el del sistema en lugar del del ambiente.

Comment: Es correcto. Utilice los comandos que mencionas y efectivamente la ruta es hacia el sistema. ¿Cómo podría arreglar esta situación?

Comment: Pues parece que el script activate.bat no está funcionando. ¿Estás lanzándolo desde una terminal CMD o desde un PowerShell?

Comment: Lo estoy lanzando desde CMD

Comment: Pues ya lo único que se me ocurre es que la carpeta donde está el venv (o la ruta hasta ella) contenga algún caracter "raro". Creo que hay un bug por el cual activate.bat no funciona si ruta contiene paréntesis en algún lugar. Tal vez haya más caracteres "problemáticos". Una alternativa es usar powershell en vez de cmd y activar el entorno con el comando `Scripts\activate.ps1`, y cruzar los dedos para que éste no dé problemas.

Answer (score 0):

El ambiente virtual te hace una copia en limpio del intérprete de Python. Esto es para crear un lugar dónde los paquetes que instales estén ajenos del sistema.

Uno de los casos de uso para el uso de los venv es cuando tienes varios proyectos con diferentes versiones de una misma librería, por lo que no sería conveniente que cuando crearas un nuevo ambiente virtual te copiara a ese entorno todas las librerías que tienes.
Algo interesante a recalcar es que cuando instales las librerías, si ya la tienes instaladas en el sistema pues lo usa como caché